Lower Pachyphytum leaves withering - what can I do?
I have a Pachyphytum that is generally doing fine. There are new leaves at the top, and it's growing, slowly, but steadily.
However, it seems to be losing its lower leaves. One by one they are withering up and falling off...

It's planted in cactus and succulent mix, and lives on a windowsill that gets loads of light. The other two succulents in the same pot (another Pachyphytum and a Tiger Haworthia) are both doing fine.
Anyone any suggestions? Thanks

Isn't loss part of nature? Did you try less water or more? I'd separate the babies and replant mama lower.

@YosefBaskin Sure loss is part of nature, but it's often a sign that I'm doing something wrong. I was hoping to keep as many leaves as possible. I wondered about separating the baby, but wasn't sure if cutting it off and replanting would work. Not sure how well it's going to do down there anyway
